# Why does System.Windows.Forms.HtmlDocument require full trust?

Tags: .net, winforms, security, windows-services, dom

The HtmlDocument class has the following attribute:

[PermissionSet(SecurityAction.LinkDemand, Name="FullTrust")]
public sealed class HtmlDocument

Why?  Can I override this somehow?  Or would i need to reflect the source and recompile?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

HtmlDocument is a wrapper for IE.  IE allows ActiveX and god knows what else and so is therefore (especially) insecure.

Comment: Right, but is full trust actually required for it to function, or is the full trust requirement a security precaution on microsofts behalf?  If I somehow recompiled HtmlDocument without that full trust attribute, would it work?